# When i press edit, it will not automatically fills the input text from the table

Tags: php, mysqli, get

on the index.php there link edit, when i press edit it should be redirect to edit.php and fill the form automatically based on row i pressed edit, but it wont fill based on the table

index.php

```
 <?php 
 $tampil="SELECT * FROM obat";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$tampil);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?=$row['id_obat']?></td>
       <td><?=$row['namaObat']?></td>
       <td><?=$row['jenisObat']?></td>
       <td><?=$row['stok']?></td>
       <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="edit.php">Edit</a>
           <a class="btn btn-danger" href="">Delete</a>
           </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
     }
?>
```

edit.php

```
<?php 
    include('config.php');

        $id_obat = 'id_obat';
        $namaObat = 'namaObat';
        $jenisObat = 'jenisObat';
        $stok = 'stok';

        if (isset($_GET['id_obat'])) {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM obat WHERE id_obat=$id_obat";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        }
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="edit.php">
          <div>
            <label>Nama Obat</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="namaObat" value="<?=$namaObat?>">
        </form>
```

Comment: Enable error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and `mysqli_error($conn)`, what did those throw back? while also looking at the HTML source.

Comment: the result when i press the link is not from the table but just the variable one

Comment: The href link to edit.php does not include any parameters yet you are checking for a parameter of `id_obat` in edit.php. Change your href to include the ID that you want to edit. `<td><a class="btn btn-success" href="edit.php?id_obat=<?php echo $row['id_obat'];?>">Edit</a>`

Comment: already change to <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="edit.php?id_obat=<?php echo $row['id_obat'];?>">Edit</a> still  same, can't fetch

Answer (score 0):

The `href="edit.php"` doesnt have a get parameter after it. i.e `href="edit.php?id_obat=<?php echo $row['id_obat'];?>"`

In the edit page you are not assigning the GET Param to the `$id_obat` you are just assigning the string id_obat.

You should firstly look into  [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and escape any GET params or even better use [Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Please use the below as an example and look into the 2 links I have posted to protect your DB. Changes are...do your check for the GET param and then assign it to the var.

```
include('config.php');       
    $namaObat = 'namaObat';
    $jenisObat = 'jenisObat';
    $stok = 'stok';

    if (isset($_GET['id_obat'])) {
        $id_obat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id_obat']);

        $sql="SELECT * FROM obat WHERE id_obat=$id_obat";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="edit.php">
      <div>
        <label>Nama Obat</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="namaObat" value="<?=$namaObat?>">
    </form>
```